List of Images are not showing in React Native Application
I am new to react native and working on personal project. I am trying to show list of image card but images are not visible. Sometime few images are visible but same image is not visible next time.
I tried react native image as well as expo-image but nothing is working. I have checked the image URL working on browser also tried solution provided on stack overflow and other sources.
Please find below the Project details
package.json
{
    "name": "foodify-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "expo-router/entry",
    "scheme": "foodify-app",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start",
        "android": "expo start --android",
        "ios": "expo start --ios",
        "web": "expo start --web",
        "test:types": "tsc",
        "lint": "eslint src --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
        "ts:check": "tsc"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@expo/config": "^8.1.1",
        "@expo/metro-config": "^0.10.0",
        "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
        "axios": "^1.6.8",
        "expo": "~50.0.14",
        "expo-constants": "^15.4.6",
        "expo-font": "^11.10.3",
        "expo-image": "^1.12.13",
        "expo-linking": "^6.2.2",
        "expo-router": "^3.4.8",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
        "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.73.6",
        "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.11",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.8.2",
        "react-native-screens": "^3.29.0",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
        "react-native-virtualized-view": "^1.0.0",
        "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
        "typescript": "^5.4.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
        "@types/react": "^18.2.79",
        "@types/react-native": "^0.73.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2"
    },
    "private": true
}

app.json
{
    "expo": {
        "name": "foodify-app",
        "slug": "foodify-app",
        "scheme": "foodify-app",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "orientation": "portrait",
        "icon": "./src/assets/icon.png",
        "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
        "splash": {
            "image": "./src/assets/splash.png",
            "resizeMode": "contain",
            "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
        },
        "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
        "ios": {
            "supportsTablet": true
        },
        "android": {
            "adaptiveIcon": {
                "foregroundImage": "./src/assets/adaptive-icon.png",
                "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
            }
        },
        "web": {
            "favicon": "./src/assets/favicon.png"
        },
        "plugins": ["expo-router", "expo-font"]
    }
}

metro.config.js
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config");

/** @type {import('expo/metro-config').MetroConfig} */
const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

module.exports = config;

Item.tsx
import {
    View,
    Text,
    ImageSourcePropType,
    Pressable,
    TouchableOpacity,
    TouchableWithoutFeedback,
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
} from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { Link, router } from "expo-router";
// import {Image} from "expo-image";

const Item = ({
    title,
    src,
    vendorId,
}: {
    title: string;
    src: string;
    vendorId: string;
}) => {
    console.log(src);
    return (
        <View className="w-[95%] h-[200] border-1 items-center align-center self-center mb-3 rounded-t-2xl border-x-cyan-50">
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                onPress={() => {
                    console.log("onpress image clicked........");
                    router.push({
                        pathname: "(item)/food-item",
                        params: { vendorId: vendorId },
                    });
                }}
            >
                <Image
                    source={{
                        uri: "https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png",
                    }}

                    // style={styles.image}
                />
                {/* <Image
          className="w-[100%] h-[80%] bg-slate-300 rounded-t-2xl"
          // style={{width:200,height:200}}
          source={{uri:src, width: 100, height: 100}}
        /> */}

                {/* <Image
          // className="w-[100%] h-[80%] bg-slate-300 rounded-t-2xl"
          style={{width:'100%',height:200}}
          source={'https://picsum.photos/seed/696/3000/2000'}
        /> */}

                {/* <Image source={{ uri: require('../assets/images/veg.png') }} style={{ width: "100%", height: 200 }} /> */}
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            <View className="pl-2 items-start border-2 border-gray-300 border-t-white w-[100%] h-[20%] ">
                <Text className="text-xl text-center font-semibold">
                    {title}
                </Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
    },
    image: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
    },
});

export default Item;


Ensure that your image URLs are correct, verify that your image components have proper dimensions and layout styles, and check if there are any network issues or caching problems affecting image visibility

Image URL and dimensions are correct and no network issue.
